# Reverse for 'program' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['home/(?P<program_id>[0-9]+)/program/$']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

when i added the url it showing this error

```
        {% for prgmm in programinfo.all %}
      <a href="{% url 'program' prgm.id %}">

                 <div id="prgmm" style="width:50%">
                   <img src="{{ prgmm.titleimage.url }}" alt="">
                 </div>
      </a>
```

my url is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='home'),
    path('<int:services_id>/', views.details, name='details'),
    path('<int:prgm_id>/program/', views.program, name='program')
```

and my view:

```
    def program(request, prgm_id):
programdetail = get_object_or_404(prgm, pk=prgm_id)
return render(request, 'program.html', {'programdetail': programdetail})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have wrote "prgm.id" instead of "prgmm.id" in your url part